# Why is function not valid as React child?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to convert my class based component to functional (stateless) component.I'm getting this error each time :

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of ...

Here is my component:

```
 const ProfileStories = (props) => {
  const renderStory = () => {
    const data = props.userStory ? props.userStory.data : [];
    if (props.isClicked) {
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderStoryItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          numColumns={2}
        />
      );
    } return null;
  };

  const renderStoryItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <StoryItem
        key={item.id}
        content={item.content}
        date={item.createdAt}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <CenterView>
      {renderStory}
    </CenterView>
  );
};

export default ProfileStories;
```

Comment: Like both answers say, you need to execute the function. JSX syntax is equivalent to *running* the component function, not passing it as a value, which is what you're doing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
return (
  <CenterView>
    {renderStory}
  </CenterView>
);
```

You are passing renderStory, which is indeed a function. You probably intended to pass the result of the renderStory function as a child to CenterView, like this:

```
return (
  <CenterView>
    {renderStory()}
  </CenterView>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

As always, components must be rendered using the `<...>` syntax. To do that, you will be also forced to uppercase the name of the component:

```
const RenderStory = () => {
}
...
return (
    <CenterView>
      <RenderStory />
    </CenterView>
 );
```

This is basically the same as directly calling the function:

```
return (
  <CenterView>
    {renderStory()}
  </CenterView>
);
```

However, your inner function is not a real component as it is written. For one thing, it uses `props` of its "parent" component. To make it a real component, you should pass any `props` to it directly. Currently it is only an inner function.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [@hansn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3719266/hansn)'s answer:

The problem you are facing is that you are passing an internal function (`renderStory`) as children. What React is expecting is a `jsx component` or null: which is what your function returns. What you should do is simply call it explicitly:

```
 <CenterView>
   {renderStory()}
 </CenterView>
```

Moreover, in order to make stateless functional components more reusable, I would suggest you split your single component `ProfileStories` into 3:

```
const Story = (props) => (
  <FlatList
    data={props.data}
    isClicked={props.isClicked}
    renderItem={props.renderItem}
    numColumns={2}
  />
);

Story.defaultProps = {
  data: []
}

const StoryItem = (item) => (
  <StoryItem
    key={item.id}
    content={item.content}
    date={item.createdAt}
  />
);

const ProfileStories = (props) => (
  <CenterView>
    <Story
      data={props.data}
      isClicked={props.isClicked}
      renderItem={StoryItem}
    />
  </CenterView>
);
```